# Java Random Number Count Error?

Tags: java, random

I have a timing method to compare different versions of a RandomCount class.

```
  public long timer() throws IndexingError{
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    randomise();
    return (((long) System.currentTimeMillis() - time)/1000);
}
```

However when I run it in it's test class it doesn't appear with anything despite the fact that I have a System.out.println in there to print the times.

```
 public void test() throws IndexingError {
    double timer1;
    double timer2;

    CleverRandomCount cleverrandomtest = new CleverRandomCount(100000);
    timer1 = cleverrandomtest.timer();
    System.out.println(timer1);

    SimpleRandomCount simplerandomtest = new SimpleRandomCount(100000);
    timer2 = simplerandomtest.timer();
    System.out.println(timer2);
}
```

Am I missing some extra lines that will help print the times for both random counts?

Comment: Well presumably the problem is with `System.out.println` not doing anything for you, which is completely orthogonal to what you're printing. Reduce your code to just `System.out.println("test")` and work out where that's going first...

Comment: Ensure that IndexingError is not thrown

Comment: Without seeing the main of your program it is hard to tell. Are you redirecting system.out anywhere? Also, add something to your outs that will show whether or not they are being called at all, like
    System.out.println("Timer 1: " + time1);

Comment: What `toString` does for `CleverRandomCount`/`SimpleRandomCount`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible issues that you should test.

## 1 An exception could be getting thrown.

Instead of throwing an indexing exception wrap the contents of test in a try catch block and print when an exception is thrown. Note: it could potentially be throwing a different exception too)

## 2 Your random function isn't working how you expect.

To test this change the system.out.println(timer) to system.out.println("timer 1 or 2" + timer). This ensures that you always know when the print happens. If timer was null your version could look like it wasn't getting printed.

## 3 If it still doesn't work try adding a System.out.flush() at the bottom.

Note: it really shouldn't be this but I have seen Java behave wierdly on different systems.